# Merge and filter data from multiple google sheets tabs

Tags: google-sheets

I have 3 google sheets tabs, all with the same columns and would like to add a 4th tab that displays all of the data from the other 3 tabs where column K = "Q116".

Importing all of the data from the 3 sheets is easily achieved:
=query({'Sheet 1'!A3:Q50;'Sheet 2'!A3:Q50;'Sheet 3'!A3:Q50})

However, I can't work out how to add a filter/where clause to only return results where column K (in all sheets) = 'Q116'.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When using QUERY on a vertical array, you need to use the column numbers in the where clause.  Try this formula:

`=query({'Sheet 1'!A3:Q50;'Sheet 2'!A3:Q50;'Sheet 3'!A3:Q50},"where Col11 = '"&Q116&"'")`

Comment: After briefly flashing some results on the screen, it returns a #ref error

Comment: there is a risk of a circular reference I think.  Your dataset is 150 rows and your search field is in row 116.  So if the query returns more than 115 rows then you will get #REF.  Can you move the search term out of column Q, or move it further down after row 150?

Comment: Thanks! Removing the "& &" solved it:

=query({'Sheet 1'!A3:Q50;'Sheet 2'!A3:Q50;'Sheet 3'!A3:Q50},"where Col11 = 'Q116')